# Cohomology ring of projective bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm following Fulton's explanation in "Young Tableaux", Appendix B.4

We consider a vector bundle $E \to X$ and its associated projective bundle $p: \mathbb P(E) \to X$. There is a tautological line bundle $L \to \mathbb P(E)$ and a pullback bundle $p^*(E)$, and a tautological exact sequence
$$
0 \to L\to p^*(E) \to Q \to 0
$$
Let $\zeta := -c_1(L) \in H^\bullet(\mathbb P(E))$. If $U$ is a trivializing open set of $X$, then $\mathbb P(E|_U) = U \times \mathbb P^{e-1}$, and $\zeta$ restricts to a class in $H^\bullet(U \times \mathbb P^{e-1}) = H^\bullet(\mathbb P^{e-1})$. The axioms of Chern theory ensures that it restricts to the hyperplane generator in degree 2. So far I understand everything.

Then Fulton says it follows by an easy Mayer-Vietoris argument that $H^\bullet(\mathbb P(E))$ is free over $H^*(X)$ with basis $1, \zeta, \zeta^2, \dots, \zeta^{e-1}$. How exactly does the Mayer-Vietoris argument go? I have only used it before in very simple cases, such as the sphere with only the two hemispheres. I'm not even sure what I should be taking as my two sets in this case. Should I decompose $X$ into an open cover of such $U$'s and induct?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is a direct consequence of Leray-Hirsch Theorem. Let $i:\Bbb CP^e\to \Bbb P(E)$ be the inclusion of fiber. We know that $\zeta$ restricts to the generator $i^\ast(\zeta)=-c_1(\gamma)$ of $H^2(\Bbb CP^e;\Bbb Z)$ on each fiber because the line bundle $L\to \Bbb P(E)$ restricts to the tautological line bundle $\gamma\to \Bbb P(E|_x)=\Bbb CP^e$ for each $x\in X$, and it follows from the cohomology ring structure of $\Bbb CP^e$ that the restriction of $\zeta^k$ must generate $H^{2k}(\Bbb CP^e;\Bbb Z)$ because $i^*(\zeta^k)=i^*(\zeta)^k$. This means that these classes form a basis of the cohomology ring of each fiber. Leray-Hirsch Theorem implies that $\{1,\zeta,\zeta^2,\ldots,\zeta^{e-1}\}$ form a basis of $H^\ast(\Bbb P(E);\Bbb Z)$ regarded as a free module over $H^*(X;\Bbb Z)$.

I think that the same argument with $\Bbb Z_2$ coefficient works when dealing with real projective space bundles.

Comment: I appreciate this perspective, but in this question, I am asking how to complete the approach suggested by Fulton, ie by using MV sequence.

Comment: @staedtlerr I tried to apply MV argument. I think that it would be based on using an open cover of $X$, but we really need $X$ to have a finite cover in order to use induction (we can't do much if the best we can achieve is to decompose it as a union of infinitely many pieces), and this is not guaranteed for any $X$. Does the author assume additional properties on $X$ other than it being a smooth manifold? (e.g., can we assume compactness?)